# Gunicorn giving me Module Not Found Error

Tags: python, django, import, gunicorn

I'm attempting to build a Django blog.

I have a couple of apps in there, but for some reason Gunicorn is giving me trouble with the error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.wsgi'`

```
├── Procfile
├── blog
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   │   ├── 1820-3-large.jpg
│   │   ├── 1820-3-large_XGHcfcZ.jpg
│   │   ├── 1820-3-large_ZTmLkYt.jpg
│   │   ├── 1820-3-large_dPbPsPW.jpg
│   │   └── paul-morris-144777.jpg
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20171217_0000.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20171217_0000.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── posts
│   │   │       ├── css
│   │   │       ├── img
│   │   │       │   └── home.jpg
│   │   │       └── js
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── posts
│   │   │       ├── home.html
│   │   │       └── post_details.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── sitepages
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __pycache__
│       │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
│       │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── migrations
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   └── __pycache__
│       │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── static
│       │   └── sitepages
│       │       ├── css
│       │       │   └── about.css
│       │       ├── img
│       │       └── js
│       ├── templates
│       │   └── sitepages
│       │       └── about.html
│       ├── tests.py
│       └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
└── venv
```

`

This is the bulk of my file tree as I see it. I don't see any issues, but I'm definitely overlooking something. Let me know if you'd like to see any other pieces of code.

My Procfile says -

`web: gunicorn blog.wsgi --log-file -`

This is my wsgi.py file -

This is wsgi.py -

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blog.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Try `blog.blog.wsgi`? Two levels.

Comment: @FlipperPA Now it gives me the error - `No module named 'blog.settings'`

Comment: We are making progress. Take a look at wsgi.py - I’m guessing the path to your setting file is also off by one level.

Comment: @FlipperPA, I appreciate the help. I've updated the problem with wsgi.py

Comment: Unfortunately gunicorn isn’t my forte, but hopefully someone can figure out the rest from here. Good luck!